# Compare two date strings in python (given in specified format in List)

Tags: python

I have two date strings in a list (i.e dateList = ['2013-11-26 08:09:51', '2013-11-26 01:19:51'])

If their is possiblility to compare between date strings of specified format, please provide a solution by returning latest date from the list.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your "question" looks like a school excercise, not like a qustion. Brute answer would then be "yes". But what have you tried so far? Did you have a look to `time`, and more precisely to `time.strptime` function? See: http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html?highlight=time%20format#time.strptime

Comment: ISO formatted dates can be compared as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...please provide a solution by returning latest date from the list.

```
max(dateList)
```

Because of the formatting of your strings (i.e. starting with the largest time unit and working step by step to the smallest, additional zeroes for single-digit values), they can be directly compared to one another.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for two different things Compare the dates and get the latest date:

To get the latest date use @jonrsharpe solution:

You can compare them as strings, by using `all()`, I'm using all so it can work with lots of dates and not just 2:

```
dateList = ['2013-11-26 08:09:51', '2013-11-26 08:09:51']

if all(dateList[0] == x for x in dateList):
    print "Equal"
else:
    print "Not equal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library:

```
from dateutil import parser
dateList = [parser.parse(date) for date in dateList]
latest_date = max(dateList)
```

It will give you latest date.

:)